# Java: Limiting characters in a string

Tags: java, string, character, java.util.scanner

how would I go at accepting SPECIFIC characters by a user through a Scanner and String?

E.g. if I wanted only two characters, "*" and " " (a whitespace) used for an input. Everything else would be invalid and would prompt the user that it's insufficient and redo the entry without submitting.

Cheers!

Comment: regular expressions and while loops ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
if (!(input.matches("[ *]*"))) {
    System.out.println("Please use only space and * characters");
    // do something that causes program to loop back and redo input
}
```

`matches` tests whether the entire `input` string matches the pattern.  The pattern is matched by a sequence of zero or more characters in the character class (the second `*` means zero or more occurrences), and the character class consists of the two characters space and `*`.

If you need the input to be at least one character, change the second `*` to `+`, but also change the error message.  Or add a separate `input.isEmpty()` test.

As to the `Scanner`: use `scanner.nextLine()` to input an entire line.  (Other `Scanner` methods tend to stop when they see space characters, which isn't what I think you want here.)

Comment: Very simple and it got the job done splendidly! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx character set exclusion:

```
if (input.matches(".*[^* ].*")) {
    //wrong input
} else {
    //ok!
}
```

Note that will pass an empty string as valid, it is up to your use case to additionally verify length of the string or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check content of string *after* it was entered then you can check if it matches regex `[* ]+` which means: series of one or more (`+` quantifier) of characters `'*'` or `' '` (space).

code:

```
System.out.print("Please provide string containing only spaces or * : ");
String userInput = //read input from user
while(!userInput.matches("[* ]+")){
    System.out.println("Your input was incorrect.");
    System.out.print("Please provide string containing only spaces or * : ");
    userInput = //read input from user
}
//here we know that data in userInput are correct
doSomethingWithUserData(userInput);
```